# How do I get Vim's project plugin to load the in.vim on external buffer change?

Tags: project, vim

I'm using the [project plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69) in Vim. For each project I'm working on, I have set up an own in.vim/out.vim where the project-specific stuff gets set.

For example, I set a shiftwidth of **2** in the in.vim, whereas in my .vimrc, I set it to **4**. When I'm opening a file from the project tree, everything is fine: the sw is 2. Now, I compile the sources (Visual Studio) and get some compiler errors/warnings. Switch to Visual Studio, fix the errors, back to Vim then.

My editor did realize that I changed the file outside the editor and asks me to reload the file. After confirming the reload, the sw is set to **4**.

Obviously, this is because the .vimrc is getting read on buffer reload and overwrites my setting of the shiftwidth stored in the in.vim configuration file.

My question is: is there any way to bring the project plugin (or vim itself) to load the in.vim upon buffer refresh?

#### Solution

The answer of [ZyX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361482/how-do-i-get-vims-project-plugin-to-load-the-in-vim-on-external-buffer-change/4363307#4363307) pointed me to a handling that works for me:

1. In the in.vim, set a global variable to the path of in.vim:

   `let g:invimpath = "D:/project/vimstuff/in.vim"`
2. In the .vimrc, try to load this specified file when `FileChangedShellPost` occurs:

   `autocmd FileChangedShellPost * if exists("g:invimpath") | exe 'source ' . g:invimpath | endif`

Credits go to ZyX to point me to this path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is, with `FileChangedShellPost` autocommand, but I suggest you first add the following just before the beginning of your vimrc (but after `scriptencoding` statement, if it is present):

```
if exists("s:vimrc_loaded")
    finish
endif
let s:vimrc_loaded=1
```

Comment: Doesn't really work for me: putting the `FileChangedShellPost` into the in.vim I'm using has no success. I cannot put it into the vimrc since the in.vim file is different for each project...